# Not able to see windows option while installing Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Ubuntu, and trying my best after googling for details.
But not able to get the solution, hence landed here.

I had Windows 7 installed on my desktop PC. 
Downloaded Ubuntu ISO.
Created USB installer using Universal USB Installer.
But made a mistake and **chose my D drive rather than USB drive**.
Then after restart, I started getting Ubuntu options for install, but it was installing , and windows boot option was not present.

So, I was not able to use Windows OS.
I finally created correct USB installer on my laptop, and now when i use that USB on my desktop, then it is showing Ubuntu options only, but atleast it is moving forward and showing steps for Ubuntu installer.
I am not sure whether it will delete my windows data, so what should i do in this case, so that I can use Ubuntu and Windows both? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

In the ubuntu setup, select **Something Else** and select a drive partition on which windows isn't installed to install ubuntu.